# Finite generatedness of singular cohomology of compact manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a compact manifold. What is your favorite proof of finite generatedness of the singular cohomology $H^*(M,\mathbf{Z})$ of $M$ that avoids invoking the isomorphism with cellular cohomology, but only uses compactness of $M$ and existence of good covers?

Could you please provide references?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have isomorphism with Cech cohomology, then it's quite immediate.

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially a trivial consequence of the existence of Mayer-Vietoris sequences.  More generally, if $M$ is a space that has a finite good cover (meaning an open cover such that all the intersections of sets in the cover are either empty or contractible), then the cohomology of $M$ is finitely generated.  The proof is a very straightforward induction on the number of sets in the good cover: if $U_1,\dots,U_n$ is a good cover of $M$, let $N=U_1\cup\dots\cup U_{n-1}$.  Then $N$ and $N\cap U_n$ both have good covers by fewer than $n$ sets ($U_1,\dots,U_{n-1}$ for $N$ and their intersections with $U_n$ for $N\cap U_n$), so by induction they have finitely generated cohomology.  Since $U_n$ is contractible, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for covering $M$ by $N$ and $U_n$ gives that the cohomology of $M$ is finitely generated.